# Too long name for portfolio site

Tags: typography, logo, branding

I'm making a portfolio website, but I have a short first name, but a long last name!

Wxxx - first name

Vxx Dxx Dxxxxxxxx - last name

I've started with a logo with just my first name or something like VVDD, but I'm not convinced - I think nobody will remember me with those initials.  And full-written my name is too long to put it in a header.

Anyone some ideas on how to sell yourself with a long name..?

Comment: why are you afraid to tell you name ? :P

Comment: Because s/he would like not to be stalked?

Comment: We can't answer this question with so little information. Why are you against a long name? Why won't a long name fit in your header? Why can't you redesign the header? What's wrong with your name as it is? What kind of portfolio? Who are you targetting? What are your goals? What does your logo look like right now?

Comment: p.s.: based on the username (woutvdd) and the Wxxx pattern, his name is Wout.

Answer (score 4):

**Be creative !**  *Have fun!*

A few suggestions:

Only use the first name as a "brand" and the last name sort of like a tag line, something like this:

[image]

**Or as an alternative:**

Invent a name that represents who you are and what you do...

Maybe try acronyms of your first name or full name shortened or just words you like(ex. design, creative, detail, etc).

Play with colors maybe... like: Blue Wout , or Grey DD... dono, that kind of stuff.

If its for yourself and you're a creative then.. the sky is the limit, you can come up with all sort of abreviations and stuff

Answer (score 2):

If this is a portfolio of your work to show prospective employers, go ahead and use your full name. If it can be spelled and pronounced easily in your native language, it's not that much trauma to use it on the Internet. They're going to be picking it up off your email anyway.

If this is a portfolio which you're using to freelance, you might want to create a shorter "doing business as" name, like Blue Moon Graphics or Van Fabulous or Willy Wonderbar Logos. Flavius has some good suggestions as well.

Comment: I've decided to just make an introduction with my full name.

Answer (score 0):

theothervond.com or better yet, are you older than Kat? Go with theoriginalvond.com or therealvond.com (if you do this one you totally double play and also have a Bond-esque portrait of yourself on there).

But seriously look at Kat's site http://www.katvond.net it seems to work for her.